# Playlists are not synced after copying Music Library.musiclibrary with Music.app

Tags: itunes, backup, music

I have two Mac machines both running Music.app and I'd love to share `Music Library.musiclibrary` between the machines.

### Problems

However, after copying the .musiclibrary from one machine to the other, the playlists I created are not synced over.

Also, after I export the library from menu: `File > Library > Export Library`, the actual `library.xml` is a small XML that stores no metadata about actual songs or playlists.

### Expectation

I expect that the `.musiclibrary` would work the same way as `.photolibrary`, i.e., a portable self-contained personal collection containing all the metadata including playlists.

### Question

**How should I reliably backup and restore `.musiclibrary` between machines just as I do with `.photolibrary`?**